# `gcc-6` and Nvidia drivers on Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, nvidia

I am attempting to install the non-free Nvidia drivers (`390.48-2~bpo9+3`) from Stretch Backports : https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/nvidia-driver

`# apt-get install -t stretch-backports nvidia-driver`.

An error occurs:

```
Building for 4.16.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
Building initial module for 4.16.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.16.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/390.48/build/make.log for more information.
```

In `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/390.48/build/make.log` I find:

```
Compiler version check failed:

The major and minor number of the compiler used to
compile the kernel:

gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1)

does not match the compiler used here:

gcc-6 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


It is recommended to set the CC environment variable
to the compiler that was used to compile the kernel.
```

This should be the same version of gcc used to compile the kernel:

```
cat /proc/version 
Linux version 4.16.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1)) #1 SMP Debian 4.16.5-1~bpo9+1 (2018-05-06)
```

I remove the Nvidia packages: `# apt-get remove --purge .*nvidia.*`

And try again: `# IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 apt-get install -t stretch-backports nvidia-driver`

A different error in `make.log`:

```
The C compiler ' gcc-6' does not appear to be able to
create object files.  Please make sure you have 
your Linux distribution's libc development package
installed and that ' gcc-6' is a valid C compiler
name.

*** Failed CC sanity check. Bailing out! ***
```

Configuring `update-alternatives` to point `gcc` and `cc` at `gcc-4.9` has no effect.

```
# CC=/usr/bin/gcc-6 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 apt-get install -t stretch-backports nvidia-driver
```

is not useful.

```
# CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.9 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 apt-get install -t stretch-backports nvidia-driver
```

*still* produces the error `The C compiler ' gcc-6' does not appear to be able to create object files.`

With other attempts I have produced an error that mentions `no-pie`.  These flags had an effect but produced other errors: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/%5Bsolved%5D-cannot-compile-nvidia-driver-kernel-does-not-support-pic-mode-4175593548/

Comment: Install a complete "gcc-6" : `# apt install g++` → The missing **gcc** packages { libc6-dev, linux-libc-dev } will be installed as dependencies.

Comment: Thanks but this did not solve the problem.  `g++` was already installed.  `libc6-dev` has been upgraded to the version from stretch-backports.  Same error in log: "...' gcc-6' does not appear to be able to create object files."

Comment: I would [submit a bug](https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting) against package `nvidia-driver`.

Comment: Reported here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=901203